# Are electrons separated by a large number of unit cells in a solid coherent?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Are electrons separated by large distances in a solid coherent?

If I consider the system as being comprised of delocalized Bloch states, then electron states with a given k can interfere with each other. The delocalized nature of the Bloch basis implies to me that no matter the separation, two such electrons are coherent.

If I consider the system as being described by Wannier orbitals, however, it is not obvious to me that electrons separated by large distances should be coherent.

I understand that the infinite periodicity of the Bloch basis is an approximation and no such real solid exists, but I think I have a critical misunderstanding here.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "coherent"? If I take two hydrogen atoms at opposite ends of the universe, they do not interact with each other, yet they are both in "the same" state (e.g., the 1s state of hydrogen). Do you consider that coherent? Similarly, a Bloch state is just another type of single-particle wave function and really only applies to non-interacting electrons. It's kind of a miracle that single particle wavefunction (and, e.g., band structure diagrams or whatever) work at all for describing a solid.

Comment: I agree with hft about the vagueness of coherence in your question. If you are considering a perfect crystal without interaction between free electrons and phonon-electron interaction, Bloch basis is good since it is also the eigenstates of Hamiltonian. In this case, equivalently to what hft said, the physics can be described by the single-particle picture with Bloch states. In comparison, the Wannier states, which are the fourier transform of Bloch states, are not the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian while they still are orthonormal basis for the crystal.